# Uploading testsuite to Subversion repository

Tags: php, unit-testing, svn, automated-tests, test-suite

I want to upload my testsuite to Subversion repository. I was wondering where in the Subversion repo the test suite should be placed. At the moment we have a root folder (containing all the source code) and a documentation folder. Should we create a testing folder within the root? We also have an automatic build system that makes a new build every minute. How can we get the tests to be run automatically in parallel?

And also, if the test fails or pass how will I get to know the result of it? When it's uploaded in Subversion?

Answer (score 1):

First, the decision how to structure your code has to be discussed in your team. But I would always suggest to remove source from root and move it into separate directory. As well for docs, externals, etc.

However why do you wish to upload results into a repository?
When jusing a CI like Jenkins, TFS etc the results should be displayed on the server to be reviewed by all, not stored in svn as the results are like generated binary data usually not checked in for your own project.

Additionally why does a build system make a build every minute? Why is it not polling the source repo?

The explicit answer for your question would be checking in the result output of a test run to repository which indicates whether this test has worked or not. But I would not recommend that.

Comment: I see.. This is a project in my university. And i want to make this testsuite automated, so that this test will run everytime someone update the project files. 

"The explicit answer for your question would be checking in the result output of a test run to repository which indicates whether this test has worked or not. But I would not recommend that."

Where in Subversion repository should i put it and how do i make it automated? Shall i just creat a file named test?

Comment: Explain me your set up a little bit more. There is not enough information for me to image what you are trying to achieve. Who is building this code? What is your build automation? Is it a batch file running every minute, is it a continuous integration software?

Comment: ive 2 tests that is saved as php. I run those test throught a testsuite. I want to make it automated, i want to put it in subversion repositroy and i want it to run everytime someone change something or add something. And my question is, How do i make my test automated, how do i put it in subversion repositroy and make it run everytime someone change something or add something?

Comment: What testing framework are you using? How can you determine the outcome of the tests?
I would suggest, that you take a look to a continuous integration like jenkins: http://jenkins-ci.org/
Then you will probably see that there is no need to check in the results into svn. The process would be: Create a build job in jenkins and let it poll the subversion repo. Every time a change occurs, it will run the job. What the job does, e.g running your tests is up to you